# Calculated member disappears when rearranging columns in field list

Tags: excel, mdx, olap

I have created a calculated member with the OLAP-Tools in Excel.

Think of it like:

```
[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany] - [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Austria]
```

The parental hierarchy is `[Customer].[Customer Geography]` and and parent member is all.

The calculation works out fine.

The problem is when I add an additional field in the column section on the field list (see example down below), the calculated member disappears.

Field list before: Country, Values

After: Country, Currency, Values

Does anybody know how to solve this bug?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you "_add the additional field_" (dimension)? If it is some code (VBA, Power Query, whatever) which rebuilds the whole cube, then it should not be a surprise the calculated member does not survive.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
No I just drag and drop a already existing (no calculation is done on that) field from my table into the column section of the field list.
But this field is not in the hierachy of the calculated member could this cause the problem?